# How do I translate "Please fill out this field." on the user registration form?

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

Obviously users need to add an email address to register an account.

I'm using the Bartik theme. In Firefox and Chrome, if I don't enter a value for the email address and press submit, the form is not sent; instead, I get a JS popup, "Please fill out this field."

[image: untranslatable please fill out this field]

When I search the translation UI, I can't find this string ("Please fill out this field.")

I also can't find the string when I grep for it over the entire D8 git repository.

How do I translate this string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This message is coming from the browser and not from Drupal, so, there's not much we can do about this, except for not using HTML5 required attributes.

I have my system in French and the message comes in French, and I don't have the French language installed in my site.

Read more about this in the Drupal core issue about "[HTML5 validation is not fully accessible](https://www.drupal.org/node/1797438)".

**EDIT:** It seems that we have [a working patch that solve the problem](https://www.drupal.org/node/1797438#comment-12129494).

Answer (score 2):

You can set it in Javascript with

```
$('input[type="text"]').setCustomValidity("This is a custom message");
```

Comment: The above code will give out an error in JS console: `TypeError: jQuery(...).setCustomValidity is not a function;` It should be called like this: `jQuery('.ed_form input[type="text"]').each(function(){jQuery(this)[0].setCustomValidity("This is a custom message."); });
` as setCustomValidity is not a jQuery method but a plain vanilla JS one, so it should be called against a JS object not against a a jQuery one.